# How to disable gps lookup in android again

Tags: android, gps, listener, quit

**How am i able to Stop GPS from receiving new signals?**

Just use:

if you initialize a `LocationManager` Object

```
mLocationManager_ = (LocationManager) mContext_.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

add a location listener, GPS is starting to a GPS-Lock,

```
mLocationListener_ = new MyLocationListener(mContext_);
mLocationManager_.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener_);
```

If this lock exists, you see the GPS Signal in your status bar,
now, if you press Home, you see, the GPS is still online, because your App is still having and trying to continue your GPS lock,

so use

```
Main.mLocationManager_.removeUpdates(this);
```

to stop your App from receiving new location updates.

Comment: What is Main here. Is it application name or something else. Pls tell me

Comment: hey, mLocationManager_ is a static variable in my case, so it's just the Way i access it. It's just a LocationManager variable (you dont need it)

Comment: Thank u. I have one doubt. I want to hide the gps icon from the task bar when I stop the service of my application through menu item "disable".

Comment: For this I have written the following code          public void onDestroy() {
  
   mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
   mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
  
  
  
  
   
  } But the icon is displaying on the taskbar. Plz help me. In some links, somebody told

Comment: that u have to root ur mobile. Is it necessary "root a mobile" to disable gps icon on the task bar.Pls help me. Its urgent for me. Thank u in andvance

Comment: no, no root is necessary, if your application is checking location via GPS this icon is shown, so there may be some problems with "removeUpdates.." go it through with debugger... removeUpdates normally removes all updates (GPS requests) and the icon should disappear by default.. good luck any further question, dont hesitate to ask, or post some code

Comment: thank u. Here I have one small doubt i.e we can get the location either GPS or network. If I disable the Gps then automatically the location may come by using network. But here my requirement is whenever I click the "Enable" menu item then only the location has to display. I did not get the solution for disabling the icon on the task bar. Is my code is correct or not which i have sent above.

Comment: can i send the code to u. Pls give me ur mail id.

Comment: you can decide if you use GPS or NETWORK location service, please post your code here, so everyone has some benefit :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the solution for disabling the gps icon on the task bar when i click the disable menu.Thank you again for great suggessions.

Comment: Is it possible to disable the network in our android mobile through programming. Because I don't want the latitude and longitude through network. Thank u in advance.

Comment: yes, as described above, with:  mLocationManager_.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener_);
you look/wait for a gps connection lookup, while with
 mLocationManager_.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager. NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener_);
you check for network location, 
this is it :) good luck and never mind :) you are welcome :)